# Confidence interval for exponential distribution with MLE

Tags: exponential-distribution, maximum-likelihood, confidence-interval, gamma-distribution

Assume that $Y_1, Y_2,\dots, Y_n$ are iid samples from the exponential distribution with the density function $f_{\theta}(y) = \frac{1}{\theta}e^{\frac{-y}{\theta}}$. Assume that $\hat{\theta}$ is the MLE estimate for $\theta$. How can we given a approximately confidence interval for $\theta$ based on the asymptotic distribution of $\hat{\theta}$?

We know that $\hat{\theta}$ indicated above is $\frac{Y_1+Y_2+\dots+Y_n}{n}$ and I know that $Y1+Y2+\dots+Y_n$ has a $Gamma(n,\frac{1}{\theta})$ distribution. But I do not know how to relate this to the confidence interval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can we given a approximately confidence interval...

This is done with the asymptotic distribution of $\hat{\theta}_{ML}$ that is Gaussian

Your (correct) attempt leads to the exact confidence interval

What do you wanna do?

---

Asymptotic CI

---

$\hat{\theta}=\overline{Y}_n$

It is known that $\overline{Y}_n\dot{\sim}N\Big(\theta;\frac{\theta^2}{n}\Big)$

1. **First way to proceed**

Estimate the standard deviation of  $\overline{Y}_n$ with $\frac{\overline{Y}_n}{\sqrt{n}}$ and solve the following double inequality in $\theta$

$$-z < \frac{\overline{Y}_n-\theta}{\overline{Y}_n}\sqrt{n}<z$$

**2. Second method**

Solve in $\theta$ the following double inequality

$$-z < \frac{\overline{Y}_n-\theta}{\theta}\sqrt{n}<z$$

---

I prefer the third method, the exact one your posted in your attempt (is easier, related with a $\chi^2$

In fact, as you showed $\Sigma_i Y_i\sim Gamma(n;\frac{1}{\theta})$ thus

$\frac{2n}{\theta}\overline{Y}_n\sim Gamma(n;\frac{1}{2})=\chi_{(2n)}^2$

Thus you can solve the following doubel inequality in $\theta$

$$a<\frac{2n}{\theta}\overline{Y}_n<b$$

where $a,b$ are the quantiles of the $\chi_{(2n)}^2$

Comment: Yes, I meant the asymptotic distribution. I edited the question. But how is that done?

Comment: @b.j :see my edits in the answer

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation.